# Lemma 4.1.7. in Bruns and Herzog, Cohen-Macaulay Rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, hilbert-polynomial

I am reading Hilbert Polynomial chapter from Commutative Algebra book by Bruns and Herzog. I stuck on Lemma  4.1.7. I failed to understand how the proof goes in the second line i.e., $(1-t)^d H(t)=\sum  \Delta ^d F(n-d)t^n$ holds.

Can anyone kindly help me to understand that. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a screenshot of the proof, for who like me knows the topic but don't have the book!

Comment: I suggest you to try proving this by induction on $d$.

Comment: For d=1, $\sum \Delta F(n-1)t^n= \sum( F(n)t^{(n+1)}-F(n-1)t^n) ,$ given that $F(n)=c (\neq 0)$ for large $n$. Will it be equal to $(1-t)H(t)$ ?

Comment: I think you missed what's $F$: the book says $F(n)=a_n$, and yes, they are equal.